# Pascal ABC NET , исправьте пожалуйста код

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
Unit Unit1;

interface

uses System, System.Windows.Forms;

type
  Form1 = class(Form)
    procedure button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
  {$region FormDesigner}
  internal
    {$resource Unit1.Form1.resources}
    pictureBox2: PictureBox;
    button1: Button;
    pictureBox1: PictureBox;
    {$include Unit1.Form1.inc}
  {$endregion FormDesigner}
  public
    constructor;
    begin
      InitializeComponent;
    end;
  end;

implementation

procedure Form1.button1_Click
(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
begin
var
  TTimer:object;
end;
var
angle : real;

begin

  
angle := angle + PI * 1 / 360;
PictureBox1.Left := R * sin(angle); PictureBox1.Top := R * cos(angle);
end.
```

Условия задания такие: Создайте анимацию движения месяца вокруг Земли. Для расчета координат верхнего левого угла PictureBox1, который содержит Месяц , можно использовать Параметрическое уравнение окружности: х= Rsin(t), у = Rcos(t), где R - радиус , t - параметр, меняющий свое значение от 0 до 2П.

Проект уже создан, фон есть, picturebox планеты и месяца созданы, button также. Код написан, но не уверен, что правильно, выбивает ошибку :
Unit1.pas(40) : Неизвестное имя 'PictureBox1'

```
PictureBox1.Left := R * sin(angle); PictureBox1.Top := R * cos(angle);
```

Comment: не создан объект формы, поэтому и PictureBox1 не у чего брать

Comment: я не знаю как его создать